# How to give border to particular column and row in Excel with ALASQL (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs

I want to add border in particular column and row is it possible to add in it .
this is my code please check it . I didn't get any option to add border.

```
            columns: [
              {columnid:'email'},
              {columnid:'dob', title: 'Birthday', width:300},
              {columnid:'name'},
              {
                columnid:'name',
                title: 'Number of letters in name',
                width: '300px',
                cell: {
                  value: function(value){return value.length}
                }
              },
            ],
            row: {
              style: function(sheet,row,rowidx){
                return 'background:'+(rowidx%2?'red':'yellow');
              }
            },
            rows: {
              4:{cell:{style:'background:blue'}}
            },
            cells: {
              2:{
                2:{
                  style: 'font-size:45px;background:pink',
                  value: function(value){return value.substr(1,3);}
                }
              }
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a border cell solution. You can similar logic for column or row.

```
cell: {
    style: function(event) {
        return (event==YOUR_INPUT?'border:1px black dotted; padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px':'');
    }
}
```