# How to display border using alasql

Tags: alasql

How to add border using `alasql` in Excel. I was trying add border object report style.

```
Var reportstyle={row:{style:{borders:{left:'1px solid black '}}}}
```

It's not adding the left border. Can you please help on this

Comment: Duplicate, probably: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42508146/1531971

Comment: Its not working

Comment: What is not working? What do you want to do, what have you tried, and what results did you get. These details should be in the body of the question, [which you can Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46673800/edit) to provide the details anyone will need to help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask